# How to disable DrawerLayoutAndroid in RN?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using `<DrawerLayoutAndroid />` in React Native.

I have an overlay menu which I want to disable the sidebar for... what would be the best way to go about doing this, to make sure that when the modal is open there's no way to trigger the drawer?

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html

Comment: I'd try to do as you suggested. If isModalVisible, allow drawer navigation, else not. Makes sense to me

Comment: First, I didn't suggest anything? Second, that's the exact question I'm asking, how do you allow/disallow the drawer navigation. There's no options to override/disable it.

Comment: My bad. Sounded like you were just looking for someone to validate your thoughts to me. In any case, I've done some digging into the [source code for DrawerLayoutAndroid](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0e8b207cc34f230eb2cced3981734b522b601817/Libraries/Components/DrawerAndroid/DrawerLayoutAndroid.android.js) and haven't yet figured out a solution.

Comment: My thought was to first figure out how to cancel opening the drawer, then just cancel if the modal is open. I played a little with the [onDrawerSlide](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0e8b207cc34f230eb2cced3981734b522b601817/Libraries/Components/DrawerAndroid/DrawerLayoutAndroid.android.js#L156). Might be something there. I also set something up on rnplay. Maybe you could fork it and make it better resemble your problem. https://rnplay.org/apps/KT0_QA

Comment: Wow great, thanks for getting that in RN Play... now it's easier to play around with it.

Comment: How do I actually edit it? I click fork and it says I can't do that

Comment: you will have to fork it. Before you can do that, you may need to sign in, which you do via your github acct

Comment: When I click fork (while logged in) they said they removed forking functionality. I'll just have to copy and paste it from scratch I guess..

Comment: interesting, that's new. I do see a note in the discord#rnplay channel related to them deactivating some functionality. A copy/paste works too though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the next release 0.22 you'll be able to disable via `drawerLockMode` property

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/ec173b1a1767aa52cf85fe652044d19264def699/Libraries/Components/DrawerAndroid/DrawerLayoutAndroid.android.js#L31

Its live, but undocumented:

`<DrawerLayoutAndroid drawerLockMode="locked-closed" >`

Parameters options include

- "unlocked" default
- "locked-closed"
- "locked-open"

Comment: @glued I was working on the same feature as above and was getting the same issue as that of the user who asked the question..I went through your answer and I am not sure how to use the above..Please help me out,I am very much a beginner in Reactjs and ReactNative

Comment: @glued I saw a similar question on this portal..Its very similar to the issue I am having..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636421/react-native-how-to-use-a-common-drawer-and-toolbar-across-all-pages-with-contr
See if you can help the guy out..Thanks a lot

Comment: @blankHead it works exactly as stated in my answer http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.30/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html#drawerlockmode