# React Native:-How to use a common drawer and toolbar across all pages with control

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I am a newbie in React Native.
I wanna make a drawer and toolbar for android and ios both.
I wrote the code of drawer and toolbar in my mainpage where I have navigator.

Like for eg.

```
<Drawer>
  <Toolbar />
  <Navigator />
</Drawer>
```

So I got drawer and toolbar in all inner pages. But now the question is how do I have control over drawer and toolbar.
Like If I want one page where I dont want to show the drawer feature and I want to show/hide options on toolbar according to pages inside the application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Any other better way to achieve the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux). You can define your scene transitions in one central location, and also declare [which scenes will be wrapped by a Drawer](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/OTHER_INFO.md#drawer-side-menu-integration).

```
import {Scene, Router} from 'react-native-router-flux';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login"/>
        <Scene key="register" component={Register} title="Register"/>
        <Scene key="drawer" component={Drawer} open={false} >
            <Scene key="home" component={Home}/>
                    ....
            </Scene>
            <Scene key="products" component={Products}/>
        </Scene>

      </Scene>
    </Router>
  }
}
```

For the Toolbar actions, you can simply have a Toolbar component inside each scene.

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Toolbar/>       
      </View>
  }
}

class Products extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Toolbar/>       
      </View>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using redux (or something else alike that has a single place to keep your app state) you can make these objects references items inside your state tree. For instance, you could create a property inside your state (`store.navigationState.currentScene`) and make your `Toolbar.subtitle` points to that.

Now, everytime you navigate to a different scene, you could update your `currentScene` and the subtitle of your toolbar would also change.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this kind of navigation issues is with [react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router)
 so you can decide the route configuration of every view. You can create an element to be shown on some subelements but not on others.

Also you can know the route where you are and change elements on a component according to that. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031911/how-to-get-current-route-in-react-router-2-0-0-rc5) you can find more information about how to get that.

Comment: I'm not sure react-router is suitable for a React Native app. Maybe you meant react-native-router?

Comment: Yes of course I only wanted to explain what to use. You have to use [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux)